# Props pasadas por un componente padre haciendo un map son undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con React + JS en una app para renderizar noticias del NY Times (https://developer.nytimes.com/). El caso es que quiero renderizar las noticias más vistas de los últimos siete días ordenadas por categorías o secciones, y tengo un problema con el renderizado de mis secciones.

Aquí mi `app.js` component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ListOfSections from "./components/ListOfSections";
import getSections from "./services/getSections";

import  Navbar  from "./shared/Navbar/Navbar";

function App() {

  const [section, setSection] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSections().then(sections=>setSection(sections));  
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <ListOfSections section={section}></ListOfSections>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Aquí mi `ListOfSections` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Section from './Section';

export default function ListOfSections ({section}) {

  return (
    <div className="container_list_sections mt-4 ml-4">
        {     
            section.map(({section})=> 
            
                <Section 
                    section={section}
                />
            )
        }
    </div>
  )


};
```

Y aquí mi `Section` component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Section ({section}) {

  return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="section-container mr-4">{section}</h1>
    </div>
  )


};
```

Pues el caso es que cuando hago `console.log(section)` en el componente `Section`, me devuelve `undefined`. Pero si hago `console.log(section)` en el componente `ListOfSections`, sí que ha recibido la información a través de las `props`. Entonces... ¿por qué cuando paso la prop `section` de `ListOfSections` a`Section`, es undefined? ¿Dónde está el error? No entiendo dónde está, el resultado de momento es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias:)

Comment: Ejem... ¿sabes que has colgado la pregunta en SO en español?

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no me había dado cuenta, la traduzco, perdona.

Comment: Esto parece un error de sintaxis `section.map(({section})=>`; ¿No es `section.map((section)=>` ?

Comment: Efectivamente, con esto ya funciona, gracias :)